# How to correctly draw a polygon roi?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to draw a polyline/polygon ROI around a rounded text so that I can straighten it to perform OCR. IM using cyotek imagebox as it has a lot of functions inbuilt like zoom, pan move etc.

Now I'm able to draw the roi but when I draw roi with image zoomed in/out the scaling factor go bonkers and I dont get the roi at the correct location. I can correctly draw and save when the image is at 100%.

Here is the example image I used. The red one is the one I draw, the green is the image which is actually being saved :

[image: Test Image]

Here is the code I'm using :

```
       private Rectangle GetBoundingRectangle(List<Point> points)
    {
        int minX = int.MaxValue;
        int minY = int.MaxValue;
        int maxX = int.MinValue;
        int maxY = int.MinValue;

        foreach (Point point in points)
        {
            if (point.X < minX)
                minX = point.X;
            if (point.Y < minY)
                minY = point.Y;
            if (point.X > maxX)
                maxX = point.X;
            if (point.Y > maxY)
                maxY = point.Y;
        }

        int width = maxX - minX + 1;
        int height = maxY - minY + 1;

        return new Rectangle(minX, minY, width, height);
    }

    private List<Point> polygonPoints = new List<Point>();
    private bool isDrawing = false;
    private Image<Bgr, byte> frame1;

    private void imageBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       

        if (isDrawing)
        {
            isDrawing = false;

            if (polygonPoints.Count > 1)
            {
               
                Point[] polygonPointF = polygonPoints.ToArray();
                using (VectorOfPoint polygonVector = new VectorOfPoint(PointFToPoint(polygonPointF)))
                {
                    using (UMat roiMask = new UMat(frame1.Height, frame1.Width, DepthType.Cv8U, 1))
                    {
                        CvInvoke.FillPoly(roiMask, polygonVector, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255));

                        // Convert the mask to a Mat
                        Mat roiMat = new Mat();
                        roiMask.CopyTo(roiMat);

                        // Convert the extracted region to a BGR image
                        Mat roiBgr = new Mat();
                        CvInvoke.BitwiseAnd(frame1, frame1, roiBgr, roiMat);

                        // Save the extracted image
                        string outputPath = "extracted_roi.png";
                        roiBgr.Save(outputPath);
                        MessageBox.Show($"Extracted ROI saved to {outputPath}", "ROI Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }

            polygonPoints.Clear();
            imageBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void imageBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if (isDrawing)
        {
            polygonPoints.Add(e.Location);

            // Draw the points on the image
            DrawPolygonOnImage();

            imageBox1.Refresh(); // Trigger the control to repaint
        }
    }

    private void imageBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            polygonPoints.Clear();
            polygonPoints.Add(e.Location);
            isDrawing = true;
        }
    }

    private void imageBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (polygonPoints.Count > 1)
        {
            using (var pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 2))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, polygonPoints.ToArray()); //red polyline
            }
        }
    }


    private Point[] PointFToPoint(Point[] points)
    {
        Point[] result = new Point[points.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = new Point((int)Math.Round((double)points[i].X), (int)Math.Round((double)points[i].Y));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void DrawPolygonOnImage()
    {
        if (frame1 != null)
        {
            using (Mat tempImage = frame1.Clone().Mat)
            {
                Point[] polygonPointF = polygonPoints.ToArray();
                float scaleX = (float)tempImage.Width / imageBox1.ClientSize.Width;
                float scaleY = (float)tempImage.Height / imageBox1.ClientSize.Height;

                int translationX = -imageBox1.HorizontalScroll.Value;
                int translationY = -imageBox1.VerticalScroll.Value;

                Point[] scaledPolygonPoints = ScalePolygonPoints(polygonPointF, scaleX, scaleY, translationX, translationY);

                using (VectorOfPoint polygonVector = new VectorOfPoint(scaledPolygonPoints))
                {
                    CvInvoke.Polylines(tempImage, polygonVector, true, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                }

                imageBox1.Image = tempImage.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
    }

    private Point[] ScalePolygonPoints(Point[] points, float scaleX, float scaleY, int translationX, int translationY)
    {
        Point[] scaledPoints = new Point[points.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            int scaledX = (int)Math.Round((points[i].X + translationX) * scaleX);
            int scaledY = (int)Math.Round((points[i].Y + translationY) * scaleY);
            scaledPoints[i] = new Point(scaledX, scaledY);
        }
        return scaledPoints;
    }
```

Comment: You need to track your zooming and subimaging and revert thst for each of the roi points.